# any function available to find the current date and time of the server in runtime using PHP

Tags: php, datetime, rss

any function available to find the current date and time of the server in runtime using PHP as  I need to pass this current date and time to the tag "Publish date / Pub date" in RSS feeds.

Please forgive me if the question is so simple.

Regards
Gourav.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) or [`getdate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php), or any of [the many other similar functions that PHP has for dealing with dates](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

`date()` will give you a date based on a format string. There are [several builtin format strings, including one for RSS `DATE_RSS`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types).

`getdate()` will give you an associative array containing pretty much all of the info you need:

```
Array
(
    [seconds] => 40
    [minutes] => 58
    [hours]   => 21
    [mday]    => 17
    [wday]    => 2
    [mon]     => 6
    [year]    => 2003
    [yday]    => 167
    [weekday] => Tuesday
    [month]   => June
    [0]       => 1055901520
)
```

from there, your can format it to what RSS needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm  
$today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01  
$today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001  
$today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310  
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01  
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.  
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001  
$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month  
$today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
```